# result set size support

Tags: php, netezza

How much result set size is supported by php for netezza database , like when query is fired for large number of records how many of them can get into result set?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only depends on how much allocated memory your script has.

Comment: so is it like for php it should be mentioned in php.ini?

Comment: Yes, the configuration directive is `memory_limit`